# How to upload file(s) to another person's Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am making an application that creates a file/folder system within multiple Google Drives. What I have so far is a main account that everything is uploaded to. The uploaded files are then shared with the multiple drives, and the permissions are changed so the receivers become the owners. This moves the uploaded files to the Drive tab, and not the Shared with Me tab.

How can I do this to directly upload files to the receivers (other user accounts), instead of all of the files going first through my drive? I am completely stumped, so I cannot provide code for you.

Thanks!

Comment: One would assume that you will need to log in to those users' accounts in order to upload files. Have you checked Google's API documentation?

Comment: @Jim I cannot do that for a few reasons: the first reason is I cannot log into their accounts (because I'm a co-op student without access), and the second reason is that there are thousands of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in two ways:
1. The way you currently do it. Only works if all users are part of the same Google apps [multi]domain.
2. This one sucks because you will need to make each user go once through an oauth (3step oauth2) flow after which you save a refresh token per user.
Advantage: works with any google/gmail account

disadvantages: security issues of saving refresh tokens and possibly malicious use. And the permission flow per user.
Seems you want #1. Whats the big deal about having them temporarily on your account?

Comment: Can you add code? I think what he was asking is code too. That is just a guess though.

Comment: The files that I upload will be permanently on my account, because there are so many that I can't delete them all. If I apply this to all the accounts, I would have about 30 000 folders in my drive.

Comment: but cant you remove them from your drive (remove the sharing to you) once you tranfered ownership?

Comment: @Zig Mandel I suppose that could work, but the application will not be running on my account in the future because I'm only working where I am for a limited time, and this program I'm working on will be here after I'm gone. Do you know if the folders/files will be uploaded to whatever account is currently logged in on the computer that runs the app? will just a basic Google Api Delete function do the trick?

Comment: Reserve a system account for it.